# Why pyright config with mason in nvim shows that package is not accessed

Tags: autocomplete, neovim, language-server-protocol, pyright

The pyright did not run well:

[image: The pyright did not run well]

Although it completes properly, it cannot find the package location:
[image: Completion status]

This is my config for pyright

```
--config python language server

lspconfig["pyright"].setup({
  capabilities = capabilities,
  on_attach = on_attach,
  settings={
      python = {
      pythonPath="/usr/bin/python3"
      },
      pyright = {}
  }
})
```

I hope someone can help me to fix the not accessed issue, I did not find a good solution on google.

Comment: Did you set `vim.g.python_host_prog` yet, You can run `:checkhealth` to check it.

Comment: No, I don't have it set up. May I know how to set it up correctly? I'm currently using Lua to set my Neovim.

Comment: Are those packages from some virtual env?

Answer (score 0):

The `"Module" is not accessed` warning means that you are importing the module, but you are not using any functions from it yet. When you start using the module the warning will disappear. This warning is useful to check for unused imports and remove them.

[before using the time module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YF84.png) 
[after using sleep from the time module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxvLJ.png)